# jq sort by value of key

Tags: json, sorting, key, jq

Given the following JSON (oversimplified for the sake of the example), I need to order the keys by their value. In this case, the order should be id > name > type.

```
{
    "link": [{
            "attributes": [{
                    "value": "ConfigurationElement",
                    "name": "type"
                }, {
                    "value": "NAME1",
                    "name": "name"
                }, {
                    "value": "0026a8b4-ced6-410e-9213-e3fcb28b3aab",
                    "name": "id"
                }
            ],
            "href": "href1",
            "rel": "down"
        }, {
            "attributes": [{
                    "value": "0026a8b4-ced6-410e-9213-k23g15h2u1l5",
                    "name": "id"
                }, {
                    "value": "ConfigurationElement",
                    "name": "type"
                }, {
                    "value": "NAME2",
                    "name": "name"
                }
            ],
            "href": "href2",
            "rel": "down"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
{
    "link": [{
            "attributes": [{
                    "value": "0026a8b4-ced6-410e-9213-e3fcb28b3aab",
                    "name": "id"
                }, {
                    "value": "NAME1",
                    "name": "name"
                }, {
                    "value": "ConfigurationElement",
                    "name": "type"
                }
            ],
            "href": "href1",
            "rel": "down"
        }, {
            "attributes": [{
                    "value": "0026a8b4-ced6-410e-9213-k23g15h2u1l5",
                    "name": "id"
                }, {
                    "value": "NAME2",
                    "name": "name"
                }, {
                    "value": "ConfigurationElement",
                    "name": "type"
                }
            ],
            "href": "href2",
            "rel": "down"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out. I tried jq with -S and -s with sort_by(), but this example is way too complex for me to figure it out with my current experience with jq. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
jq '.link[].attributes|=sort_by(.name)'
```

The `|=` takes all the paths matched by `.link[].attributes`, i.e. each "attributes" array, and applies the filter `sort_by(.name)` to each of them, leaving everything else unchanged.

Comment: `jq` is such an amazing & powerful thing... I would never have thought of that!

Comment: incredible.. i was starting to loose my hope after all the tries while the answer was so short and clean. Thank you a lot!!!! Cheers!