# JSON parsing output using jq

Tags: json

I am parsing the output from the below curl as follows -

```
 curl 'http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95765.json' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' | jq '.[][][] | select(.apparent_t>5)
```

How can retain only certain fields in the output. Expected output is

```
[
   {
      "sort_order":147,
      "lat":-33.8,
      "lon":151.1,
      "apparent_t":10.9
   },
   {
      "sort_order":148,
      "lat":-23.8,
      "lon":128.1,
      "apparent_t":7
   },
   {
      "sort_order":236,
      "lat":-33.34,
      "lon":151.74,
      "apparent_t":21.9
   }
]
```

Basically, I need to filter out only certain fields & print key, values for it. I am not able to work out th next steps for this. I'd truly appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the keys you want to extract, just ... extract those.

```
curl 'http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60801/IDN60801.95765.json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' |
jq '[.[][][] | select(.apparent_t>5) | {"sort_order": .sort_order, "lat": .lat, "lon": .lon, "apparent_t": .apparent_t}]'
```

This outputs a list of dictionaries; take out the outer `[...]` if you actually want just a dictionary at a time in a sequence of JSON fragments in the output (maybe combine with `-c` then to get one dictionary per line).

Comment: Thankyou tripleee. How could I sort this by ascending order of "apparent_t" field. Please could you help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739892/jq-sort-by-value-of-key though your case is much simpler; `jq '[.[][][] | select(.apparent_t>5) | {"sort_order": .sort_order, "lat": .lat, "lon": .lon, "apparent_t": .apparent_t}] | sort_by(.apparent.t)'`